# Python - parser over multiline text

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, text

my goal is to create a text parser for file containing multilines data:

```
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url http://prod7.team.cn/test/tracks-v1a1/mono.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://prod7.team.cn/test/tracks-v1a1/mono
[NULL @ 000001e002039000] Opening 'http://prod7.team.cn/test/tracks-v1a1/mono' for reading
[http @ 000001e00203a040] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Address 92.223.97.22 port 80
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Address 92.223.97.22 port 80
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Starting connection attempt to 92.223.97.22 port 80
[tcp @ 000001e00203ba80] Successfully connected to 92.223.97.22 port 80
[http @ 000001e00203a040] request: GET /test/tracks-v1a1/mono HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Lavf/58.31.101

Accept: */*

Range: bytes=0-

Connection: close

Host: prod7.team.cn

Icy-MetaData: 1
```

each files contain multiple set of such information.
My target is to find every "Successfully conneted" IP address, followed by the HOST detail, till LF.

In the case mentioned a valid match should be
IP 92.223.97.22 HOST prod7.team.cn

I can easily find the IP using a regex, but I don't understand how to create a valid match, skipping further lines till "host".

#### UPDATE

If I use this Regex

```
(connected to).([0-9].(?:\.[0-9]+){3}.port.*.*)
```

I find:

```
Match 1
Full match  connected to 92.223.97.22 port 80
Group 1.    connected to
Group 2.    92.223.97.22 port 80
```

I'm receiving error if I add .* or .host.* at the end. I'm confused how to add another pattergn to detect 'Host:' and get match until end of row.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

You want to run your regex in MULTILINE mode which should allow you to match over line breaks. Then you could use something like `.*` to capture the in-between.

A caveat to notice is that you should be sure to check to make a sure you don't run into a new matching start. Like `CA.*B` would match both CAB and CACB and CACAB. So most likely will want to explicitly check in your regex to not overrun the beginning of a valid match with the `.*`.

Comment: I'm receiving error if I add .* or .host.* at the end. I'm confused how to add another pattergn to detect 'Host:' and get match until end of row.

Comment: you don't want to end with .* since that will match the entire rest of the file. For deceting host it would just be appended so for example "<your-current-regex-mathcing-the-first-part>.*(\'Host\':\w*([a-z]+\.)+)$" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out using nested Regex:

```
ip_list = []
    regex = r'connected(.*?)Host[^\n]+$'
    text_as_string = open('C:\\temp\\log.txt', 'r').read()
    matches = re.finditer(regex, text_as_string, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        block = str(match.group())
        #print connected IP
        ip = re.compile('(connected to).[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}.port.*')
        for match in re.finditer(ip, block):
            f_id=match.group()
        #print connected host
        host = re.compile('Host[^\n]+$')
        for match in re.finditer(host, block):
            f_host=match.group()
        if f_id =='':
            f_id='NA'
        if f_host =='':
            f_host='NA'
        ip_list.append([f_id,f_host])
    unique_ip = reduce(lambda l, x: l if x in l else l+[x], ip_list, [])
```